# Access VPS behind VPN

Tags: windows, networking, vpn, remote-desktop, windows-server

I've a VPS running Windows Server 2022, connected to a VPN and RDP got disconnected.
How can I connect to it's RDP while it's using VPN ?
I think that I must make rules for incoming RDP to don't route over VPN.

Comment: Provide a route to the VPS on the server running the VPN, specifically, a route within the configuration of the VPN daemon itself

Comment: I don't have access to VPN server

Comment: Then you cannot ask the required changes to accomplish your goal